# Why my pdf changes its size depending if the web console is open or not using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, web, jspdf

I'm trying to download a pdf with images from various sizes, and I was able to adjust images well to the pdf but the size of the images continue changing despite I set up all the numbers like they should go.
For example it varies if I have the console open in the web or not.
I am pretty sure it's related to the web. I've tried different browsers but it's the same thing.
It sometimes changes the size and it sometimes doesn't

[jsPDF - why my pdf print sometimes shrinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129898/jspdf-why-my-pdf-print-sometimes-shrinks)

I did ask something simmilar some time ago you can have as a reference. I'd like to know why this is happening and how can I stop it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsPDF - why my pdf print sometimes shrinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129898/jspdf-why-my-pdf-print-sometimes-shrinks)

Comment: @Ouroborus nope, that is the same issue I posted some time ago but no one reached out

Comment: Yeah, the comment is a side effect of flagging a post as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). You're not supposed to ask the same question multiple times, even if you aren't getting answers. Usually you'd add a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to increase interest but it doesn't look like you have enough points to do that.